# Deliver Apple Passbook Passes (.PKPass Files) Via MMS

Tags: xcode, sms, mms, passbook

While researching text message marketing companies I came across something unique (http://www.sumotext.com/passbook-MMS.html) that I didn't know was possible.  This is the ability to be able to deliver .PKPass (Apple Passbook Passes) in MMS messages directly to iPhones.

On their site they say "Anyone can deliver Passes through companion apps, mobile landing pages, or links inside emails. But Sumotext can deliver Passes directly to mobile devices via MMS!" If you try the demo that they have in the sidebar it will have you text 'B' back and then you will be sent a MMS message that has an attachment that is a Passbook pass, this is the only time I've even seen something like this done. On my iPhone it says "Attachment: 1 Pass"

How is this possible? To attach a PKPass to a MMS message, that would be sent through a SMS/MMS sending API such as Twilio/Mogreet.  I looked through Apple's Passbook documentation and such and haven't seen anything that says it's even possible to deliver passes through a MMS message.  All I've seen was having passes delivered through email or a web link.

I don't know much about MMS but does it have to do something with changing the MMS MIME Type to the PKPass format such as 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass'?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct - to send a pass by MMS, you simply need to attach the .pkpass bundle to the message with a mime type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`.